# Probability w/ Counting

Tags: probability

The $2018$ Winter Olympics had athletes compete from $92$ different countries. Each country has selected an athlete to carry their flag in the opening ceremonies. If the countries and their flag-bearers enter the arena in random order, then what is the probability that:

(a) The first country is Canada and the last country is Mexico?

(b) The first $7$ countries correspond to the $7$ countries that begin with A (Albania, Andorra, Argentina,Armenia, Australia, Austria, Azerbaijan)?

(c) North Korea and Iran enter one after the other (either order)?

All see relatively simple and I have had some attempts at it, but I know they aren't correct because I simply can't wrap my head around it. 
My answers:

a) $90!$ possible ways for Canada to be first and Mexico to be last. 
   Probability of occurrence is $\frac {90!}{92!} = 0.00012$

b) $7!$ possible ways to order the $7$ countries.
   $85!$ possible ways to order the rest of the countries after.
   This gave me a result of $1$ which I know isn't right.

c) I can't seem to figure out if I should use $92\choose 2$ to choose the two spots 
   that North Korea and Iran will fill and then multiple by the number of 
   permutations?

Any help is much appreciated to clear my head. Thank you!

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except they don't enter the arena in random order.  Greece is always first, and then they proceed in alphabetical order in the language of the host country.

Ignoring reality and following the given assumptions.

a) is correct.

b) $\frac {7!85!}{92!}$

c) Unify the Iranian North Korean teams.  there are 91! ways for the countries enter with the unified block.  Then we separate them, and there are 2 ways for the block to enter.

$\frac {2\cdot 91!}{92!}$

Answer (score 0):

In $b)$ you don't get $1$:  $7!\cdot 85!\lt92!$  But if they come in alphabetical order,  it's just $\frac{85!}{92!}$.

Still working on $(c)$.  How about $\frac{2\cdot 91\cdot 90!}{92!}$?

$a)$ looks ok.